# Swift Mongolab Rest API

Tags: ios, swift, rest, mlab

I'm trying to learn swift, and have previously been working with Web technologies. Now when I'm trying to build similar apps swift, I find little to non documentation on the topic.

I've seen 3rd party libraries (or what it's called on iOS), but thought it could be smart to learn how the bricks are connected!

So: has anybody out there a good tutorial for creating the connection to Mongolab, and also POST and GET calls  with Swift? Or could provide the basic code to be able to POST to Mongolab?

Comment: Have you seen [Mongolab example](http://shrikar.com/how-to-make-an-app-talk-to-database-using-restkit/)?

Comment: Sort of, trying it now! Would still like to see some post-methods etc! Can't really figure out how it works... Have you ever tried it? Do you have a project on GitHub or anything?